# Why blank space appear in body layout in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-view

[image]

Blank space shows top a product details page, Please someone help to how to recover it.

**Update:**

I realized  i had a mistake in below file

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/products/onegraph/general.phtml

Comment: you probably accidentally added a ( ` ) on your layout file.

Comment: check some phtml file for your header. It should be there

Comment: I found a mistake in my file. i had a mistake in vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/products/onegraph/general.phtml

Comment: yeah . that's great

Comment: Thanks - @magefms  i  was solved the error